# Including a java inner class file to JAR using GNU make

Tags: java, gnu-make

I have a java project which uses GNU make to compile the source files and also create a JAR. After I introduced a nested enum, a new file `main_classname$inner_classname.class` is getting created.

I am having trouble including this file in the JAR.

Below is the relevant portion of my Makefile:

```
JARNAME=Project.jar

CLASSES=\
   Main.class \
   Main$$Inner.class
```

And this is an excerpt from the *targets* file that is included by the Makefile:

```
$(JARNAME): $(CLASSES)
   jar cvf $(JARNAME) $(CLASSES)
```

The inner class doesn't get added to the JAR because the shell expands the string after the dollar sign.

I tried putting a back-slash in front of $$, i.e. `Main\$$Inner.class`, but make complains:

> make: *** No rule to make target `Main\$Inner.class', needed
>   by`Project.jar'.  Stop.

Another approach was to try the following change so that the dollar is escaped, but to no avail:

```
ESCAPED_CLASSES=$(patsubst %$$,%\$$,$(CLASSES))
$(JARNAME): $(CLASSES)
   jar cvf $(JARNAME) $(ESCAPED_CLASSES)
```

What can be done to overcome this problem, especially without hard-coding special cases to the *targets* file?

Comment: Note that it is uncommon to use `make` for Java projects. The de-facto build tools for Java are [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org).

Comment: Agreed. I was just hoping to not take the big step of moving the build to `Apache ant`, which no doubt is a good decision in the long run, too. More importantly, I guessed I am not the only one using (not by choice) `make` for Java projects and people would have certainly come across such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. I use $(subst $$,\$$,$(CLASSES)) and double up the dollars (as you did).

This GNU makefile works for me:

```
JAR     =       /usr/bin/jar
CLASSES = org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser$$Token.class

executable: poo.jar

poo.jar:      $(CLASSES)
    $(JAR) cvf $@ $(subst $$,\$$,$(CLASSES))
```

Comment: Today, after such a long time, I was able to test that your solution works. Accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

(untested)

If you cannot just use a wildcard for all class files to get the file names but need to name it explicitly, you need to tell Make that your dollars signs *are* dollar signs!

This is in Make done by escaping with another dollar sign.  From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax

> Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if
>   you really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must
>   write two of them, ‘$$’ (see How to Use Variables). If you have
>   enabled secondary expansion (see Secondary Expansion) and you want a
>   literal dollar sign in the prerequisites list, you must actually write
>   four dollar signs (‘$$$$’).

In this case you want *two* real dollar signs.  According to this it means either four or even *eight* dollar signs in the Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to use `$(patsubst)` appears to be sound, but I think you're calling it incorrectly. Have you tried:

```
ESCAPED_CLASSES := $(patsubst $$,\$$,$(CLASSES))
```

Note also that you should be using `:=` instead of `=` or you'll waste lots of time re-evaluating the `$(patsubst)` every time `$(ESCAPED_CLASSES)` is expanded.

Comment: I am not very familiar with make syntax; I used % by looking at some examples and make documentation says it is wildcard character. Anyway, I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work. In fact, I tried double slashes \\ and many more things.  
Anyway, thanks for letting me know the difference between `:=` and `=`
Finally, I worked around my problem using two different variables, one containing names with backslash and the other without, which is not at all elegant I admit.
I am going to post my answer soon.

Comment: This worked for me by replacing `patsubst` by `subst`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally solved the problem, though I hope there exists a better answer. Or may be I should stop using `make` for Java projects.

I defined a new variable in the *Makefile* and this is how it looks now:

```
JARNAME=Project.jar

CLASSES=\
   Main.class\
   Main$$Inner.class

ESCAPED_CLASSES=\
   Main.class\
   Main\$$Inner.class
```

Because `ESCAPED_CLASSES` may not be necessarily defined by all the *Makefiles* that use *targets* file, I handled this in the following way so as to keep rules in *targets* file generic:

```
ESCAPED_CLASSES ?= $(CLASSES)

$(JARNAME): $(CLASSES)
   jar cvf $(JARNAME) $(ESCAPED_CLASSES)
```

`?=` will make sure that assignment takes place only if the variable is not already defined - [GNU make manual describing conditional variable assignment operator](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59)